# XDocument.Save нету перегрузки string

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core

Проблема заключается в отсутствии перегрузки. В чем может быть проблема ?

```
List<Image> outFiles = new List<Image>();
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("files.xml");
XElement root = xDoc.Element("files");
int i = 1;
foreach (XElement xe in root.Elements("file"))
{
    if (xe.Element("name").Value + xe.Element("extention").Value == src)
    {
        xe.Remove();
        continue;
    }
    outFiles.Add(new Image { Id = i, Src = xe.Element("name").Value + xe.Element("extention").Value, Selected = false });
    i++;
}

xDoc.Save("files.xml");
return outFiles;
```

Comment: Проверяйте сборки и включения пространств имен, чего-то из этого не хватает скорее всего.

Comment: @VladD поправил

Comment: `using System.Xml;`
`using System.Xml.Linq;`  Вроде есть

Comment: @Fionor: А какая у вас целевая платформа?

Comment: @VladD  ASP.NET.

Comment: @Fionor: Я имел в виду, версия .NET Framework (или .NET Core).

Comment: @VladD .Net core

Comment: @Fionor: О! Так с этого ж надо было начинать!

Comment: @VladD В принципе я могу и таким костылем обойтись `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("files.xml", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"+"\n"+xDoc.ToString());` Но все же интересно почему не работает.

Comment: А DLL тоже подключены соответствующие `System.XML` и `System.XML.Linq` в `References`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы пишете под .NET Core, это не то же самое, что .NET Framework.

.NET Core — это новая платформа, в ней ещё нету всех тех же вызовов, что есть в старом Framework.

Согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save?view=netcore-1.1), и правда `XDocument.Save` доступен только с `Stream`'ом, `TextWriter`'ом и `XmlWriter`'ом.

Должно про идее работать так:

```
using (var stream = File.Create("files.xml"))
    xDoc.Save(stream);
```